# SciPy Quad Integration: Accuracy Warning

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, numerical-integration

I am currently trying to compute out an integral with scipy.integrate.quad, and for certain values I get the following error:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py:616: AccuracyWarning: divmax (20) exceeded. Latest difference = 2.005732e-02
  AccuracyWarning)

Looking at the documentation, it isn't entirely clear to me why this warning is raised, what it means, and why it only occurs for certain values.

Comment: Could you show the simplest version of your code that generates the warning?  A quick glance at the latest scipy source code shows that warning can be raised in `scipy.integrate.romberg`, but apparently not in `scipy.integrate.quad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `scipy.integrate.quad` there's a lower-level call to a difference function that is iterated over, and it's iterated over `divmax` times.  In your case, the default for `divmax=20`.  There are some functions that you can override this default -- for example `scipy.integrate.quadrature.romberg` allows you to set `divmax` (default here is 10) as a keyword.  The warning is thrown when the tolerances aren't met for the difference function.  Setting `divmax` to a higher value will run longer, and hopefully meet the tolerance requirements.